# Zend Framework Access baseUrl() from Controller Action Helper

Tags: zend-framework

How do I access baseUrl() from a helper class in zf ?

```
function validateSession ()
{

    if (!$this->session->adminid)
    {
        $redirector = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('redirector');
        $redirector->setGotoSimple( $this->baseURL() .'/login');
        $redirector->redirectAndExit();
    }

}
```

`$this->baseUrl()` doesn't work

Comment: Which object are you at now? Is it controller, model or plugin?

Comment: This is Controller Helper

Comment: By controller helper you mean Zend_Controller_Action_Helpe.. right?

Comment: Yes it is.class Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_StaffLogin extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect form a controller using any of the below method.

```
$redirector = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Redirector');         
$redirector->gotoUrl('/url');


$redirector = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Redirector');     
$redirector->gotoSimple('my-action',
                                       'my-controller',
                                       null,
                                       array('param1' => 'test',
                                             'param2' => 'test2'
                                             )
                                       );
```

Basically you have to get the `Redirector` class/object of Zend and can apply any method they have specified in the manual [zend.controller.actionhelpers.redirector](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.redirector)